# Adding CSS shadows.Shadow appearing only in 1 side?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add shadows using the following code

```
-moz-box-shadow:0 1px 3px #B8B8B8;
-webkit-box-shadow:0 1px 3px #B8B8B8;
box-shadow:0 1px 3px #B8B8B8;
```

I am able to create this effect on sidebars,widgets,footer,etc.

However when I try to put this around the main content area,the shadow on the bottom only comes.In the other sides,theres no shadow.

I am trying to find the reason since past 2 days.Today after some googling,i thought there might be some div with a higher z-index around,but,i believe theres no div.

Google chromes inspect element has a stike on the css and reveals an error of unknown property name.Can anyone please help me.
Here is my [blog](http://ilovetrollstestbeta.blogspot.in/2013/06/test.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `overflow:hidden` on `.blog-posts.hfeed` and `#main-wrapper` remove those, or put margin: 3px on `.post`